# Grails war produces JAR file in version 3.1

Tags: grails, gradle

We're using Grails 3.1 and I'm trying to build a WAR to be run on an external Tomcat container, but when I run `grails war`, it creates a JAR file in the `<project_dir>\build\libs` directory.  How do I configure Grails to produce a WAR file?

Comment: What version of tomcat are you deploying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to 3.1.2 didn't solve the problem.  I'm using the web-api profile, so I'm not sure if things are different from the default profile.

However, I did solve this by applying the Gradle war plugin in `build.gradle`.  **Note:** originally I had the war plugin last, after the other Grails plugins; and it did not work.  It worked fine after moving it before them.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.plugins.views-json"
```

Answer (score 4):

Grails 3.1.2 was released earlier today and includes a bug fix for your issue: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9736.

Answer (score 0):

Grails 3 is using gradle.

> gradle war

And make sure you are using Tomcat 8 and above. For tomcat 7 you need to remove internal tomcat8 jars from war in the config file.